# Merge csv files if they have the same columns headers, if not split

Tags: python, database, csv, concatenation

I have a folder with several csv files (5k+), to work with them it would be ideal to have the same variable names and number of columns. But this is not the case.

To proceed for the cleaning, I would like to create some subfolders conditional on their columns. For example, if two or more csv have the same columns and variable names, create a subfolder with them.

So far I found how to combine all the files, but I don't know where to put the condition with the matching columns subfolders.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]    

col_combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
```

Comment: So you want to combine all files with the same headers together? Why would subfolders be needed? Just use a different name per header combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To merge all CSV files together with the same header in a folder, the following approach could be used:

```
import csv
import glob

csv_files = {}      # (header as tuple) : csv.writer()
header_type_count = 1

for filename in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        header = tuple(next(csv_input))
        
        try:
            csv_files[header].writerows(csv_input)
        except KeyError:
            f_output = open(f'header_v{header_type_count:02}.csv', 'w', newline='')
            header_type_count += 1
            csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
            csv_files[header] = csv_output
            csv_output.writerow(header)
            csv_output.writerows(csv_input)
```

This works by keeping track of all of the different header types and allows them to be concatenated on the fly. For each new header type found, it opens a new output CSV file (e.g. `header_v01.csv`).

`csv_files` maps header types to open `csv.writer()` objects to allow extra rows to be written.

This approach avoids needing to hold all the data in memory at the same time.